# Google - BigQuery Location Error (dataset was not found in location europe-west1)

Tags: google-bigquery

I am running a query on BigQuery and everything runs properly. However, when trying to save this query as a new table (in BQ) I get the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgaa8.png)

"Not found: Dataset mycompany-data:google_analytics_de was not found in location europe-west1 "

The aforementioned table location on BigQuery is europe-west1.
I have double-checked for spelling errors and access permissions, but this error persists whatsoever.
Can you assist me with this?

Comment: Can you check all tables in execution Query are in same Dataset location as created table location .. Generally these error occurs when you try to move data between different region(location) and if you try to store target data at same location these error may go off.